# Deploying Rails 3 app on bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bluehost

I keep receiving 500 internal server error

I followed the guide by bluehost [found here](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails) and still nothing works

~/railstest/public/.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
        #Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
        RailsEnv production
        RackBaseURI /
        SetEnv GEM_HOME /home1/railstestc/ruby/gems
```

~/.bashrc

```
export HPATH=$HOME
        export GEM_HOME=$HPATH/ruby/gems
        export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8
        export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
        export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems/bin
        export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems
```

Answer (score 1):

If click bluehost's hosting tab, and then click the RubyGems icon you'll see this nice notice down the page a bit:

```
Using Your Ruby Gem(s)
!!!!At this time Rails 3.0 is not supported and can cause a broken ruby/rails environment!!!!

You will need to add /home4/localvor/ruby/gems to the include path. 
You can do this by adding the following code to your script:
$:.push("/home4/localvor/ruby/gems")
```

<strike>In other words, Blue host current doesn't support rails 3 at all. Or rather, they don't have a javascript run time available. Sorry mate.</strike>

If you run a bundle install, then a bundle --binstubs you'll be able to use ./bin/rake and execute tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm @EJEHardenberg worked.  I had to run `bundle --binstubs` and then all of a sudden it worked.

I wouldn't use Bluehost unless you are VERY familiar with Rails and the backend setup requirements, such as Passenger (which BH uses).  It took me 6 months (I'm a noob, yes) to get the Rails env working.  Needless to say, my google-fu is much stronger now...